# FATAL EXCEPTION: main 03-26 > 13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389): java.lang.RuntimeException: > Unable to start activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

**My Code**

```
private static final LatLng AMSTERDAM = new LatLng(52.37518, 4.895439);
    private static final LatLng PARIS = new LatLng(48.856132, 2.352448);
    private static final LatLng FRANKFURT = new LatLng(50.111772, 8.682632);
    private GoogleMap map;
    private LatLngBounds latlngBounds;
    private Button bNavigation;
    private Polyline newPolyline;
    private boolean isTravelingToParis = false;
    private int width, height;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

        getSreenDimanstions();

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        bNavigation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNavigation);
        bNavigation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!isTravelingToParis)
                {
                    isTravelingToParis = true;
                    findDirections( AMSTERDAM.latitude, AMSTERDAM.longitude,PARIS.latitude, PARIS.longitude, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING );
                }
                else
                {
                    isTravelingToParis = false;
                    findDirections( AMSTERDAM.latitude, AMSTERDAM.longitude, FRANKFURT.latitude, FRANKFURT.longitude, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING );  
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        latlngBounds = createLatLngBoundsObject(AMSTERDAM, PARIS);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latlngBounds, width, height, 150));

    }

    public void handleGetDirectionsResult(ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoints) {
        PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.RED);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoints.size() ; i++) 
        {          
            rectLine.add(directionPoints.get(i));
        }
        if (newPolyline != null)
        {
            newPolyline.remove();
        }
        newPolyline = map.addPolyline(rectLine);
        if (isTravelingToParis)
        {
            latlngBounds = createLatLngBoundsObject(AMSTERDAM, PARIS);
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latlngBounds, width, height, 150));
        }
        else
        {
            latlngBounds = createLatLngBoundsObject(AMSTERDAM, FRANKFURT);
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latlngBounds, width, height, 150));
        }

    }

    private void getSreenDimanstions()
    {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        width = display.getWidth(); 
        height = display.getHeight(); 
    }

    private LatLngBounds createLatLngBoundsObject(LatLng firstLocation, LatLng secondLocation)
    {
        if (firstLocation != null && secondLocation != null)
        {
            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();    
            builder.include(firstLocation).include(secondLocation);

            return builder.build();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void findDirections(double fromPositionDoubleLat, double fromPositionDoubleLong, double toPositionDoubleLat, double toPositionDoubleLong, String mode)
    {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.USER_CURRENT_LAT, String.valueOf(fromPositionDoubleLat));
        map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.USER_CURRENT_LONG, String.valueOf(fromPositionDoubleLong));
        map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DESTINATION_LAT, String.valueOf(toPositionDoubleLat));
        map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DESTINATION_LONG, String.valueOf(toPositionDoubleLong));
        map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DIRECTIONS_MODE, mode);

        GetDirectionsAsyncTask asyncTask = new GetDirectionsAsyncTask(this);
        asyncTask.execute(map); 
    }
    }
```

**MyLogCat**

> 03-26 13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 03-26
>   13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.emildesign.navigationapplication/com.emildesign.navigationapplication.NavigationActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error
>   inflating class fragment 03-26 13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
>   03-26 13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
>   03-26 13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154) 03-26
>   13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
>   03-26 13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 03-26
>   13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 03-26 13:09:15.145:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(389):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306) 03-26
>   13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-26
>   13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 03-26 13:09:15.145:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(389):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>   03-26 13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 03-26
>   13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-26 13:09:15.145:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(389): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
>   Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment 03-26
>   13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
>   03-26 13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752) 03-26
>   13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 03-26
>   13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 03-26
>   13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 03-26
>   13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:342)
>   03-26 13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):    at
>   android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928) 03-26
>   13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at
>   com.emildesign.navigationapplication.NavigationActivity.onCreate(NavigationActivity.java:38)
>   03-26 13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):    at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5255) 03-26
>   13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
>   03-26 13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2213)
>   03-26 13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):    ... 11 more 03-26
>   13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's
>   AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4323000
>   but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the
>    element:      03-26
>   13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.t(Unknown Source)
>   03-26 13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):    at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown
>   Source) 03-26 13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):    at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.B(Unknown Source) 03-26
>   13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.A(Unknown Source) 03-26
>   13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
>   03-26 13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):    at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.gW(Unknown Source)
>   03-26 13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):    at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
>   03-26 13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):    at
>   com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source) 03-26 13:09:15.145:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(389):    at
>   com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source) 03-26
>   13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown
>   Source) 03-26 13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
>   03-26 13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
>   03-26 13:09:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(389):    ... 21 more

My Manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.emildesign.navigationapplication"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.emildesign.navigationapplication.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.emildesign.navigationapplication.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.emildesign.navigationapplication.NavigationActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

          <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="ichangeditforyou" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Activity XML

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bNavigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Navigate" />
```

Comment: What's this - `android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"` ?  And thanks for the API key.  Very useful.

Comment: check this part of your logcat: `The meta-data tag in your app's
> AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4323000
> but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the
> <application> element:     <meta-data
> android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
> android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> `

Comment: did your change my api kye? <3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is this here:

> The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value. Expected 4323000 but found 0. You must have the following declaration within the element

Add this xml to your manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: I got this error on release builds but not building direct to device. adding meta-data tag worked for me.